# Returning string from observable for SRC image attribute

Tags: angular, observable

I have an image service that, given the user_id, gives the id of the user's profile picture. Once I get that, I have to make another request to the Image Service that gives back the JPG image with the just received user's profile picture id.

Fetch the image:
`<img [src]="getProfilePicture(1) | async">`

```
Call to the imageService:
getProfilePicture(user_id) {
    return this.imageService.getProfilePictureUrl(user_id);
  }
```

Return the observable that has the string-URL

```
getProfilePictureUrl(user_id: number) {
    return this.getProfilePicture(user_id).pipe(map((data) => this.getImageUrl(data['image_id'])));
  }
```

Hard-coded string-URL:

```
getImageUrl(id: number) {
    return `${this.url}/fetch/${id}`;
  }
```

But now, I get an infinite loop of requests (because I alsways return another observable) but I don't know how to fix this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just store the observable (or the image url itself) in the component or in the user object displayed by the component.

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable in your Component

```
profilePicture : any;
```

Update method

```
getProfilePicture(user_id) {
    return this.imageService.getProfilePictureUrl(user_id).subscribe(data => {
          this.profilePicture = data;
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<img [src]="profilePicture">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the image is surrounded by a loop. It is a loop of user's commenting on the post. So each comment has a profile picture

Comment: can you post your HTML to question?

Comment: you should return list of Object from component and only use ngFor in view to display

Comment: Yes, but that is not possible. I first fetch data from the first service and afterwards I use those ID's to fetch the image ID belonging to the first id's and lastly, I use those ID's to fetch the corresponding images.